# All of my custom posttypes are 404'ing

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, theme-development, metabox

All of the posts made within custom posttypes have suddenly become uneditable, and will 404 when you try to view them.[image: Screenshot]

The posts in the admin panel are greyed out (posts in the standard post/pages etc are fine).

---

**Things I have Tried**

- I have tried using `GIT BISECT` but problem persists beyong where I know it to be working.
- Tried downgrading wordpress
- Checked various database elements such as post status and post author.
- Tried setting and resetting permalinks.
- Deactivated All plugins

---

New posts seem to be fine, and work normally. But my metaboxes have also vanished!! Again, `GIT` suggests this problem going back beyond where I know them to be working.

It seems, as `GIT` is incapable of finding the solution, that it must either be related to the database or the wordpress core itself (as my GIT repo only tracks the theme)

Wordpress is up to date.

---

**Edit**
This is the function that creates the post types:

```
register_post_type($object_name,
        array(
            'labels' => mf_create_labels($object_name),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes')         
        )
    );
```

using this to create labels:

```
function mf_create_labels($label){
    return array(
        'name' => __($label),
        'singular_name' => __($label),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', $label),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New '.$label),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$label),
        'new_item' => __('New '.$label),
        'view_item' => __('View '.$label),
        'search_items' => __('Search '.$label),
        'not_found' =>  __('No ' . $label . ' found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No ' . $label . '  found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
}
```

---

**Update**

I have got the meta boxes back, it seems Wordpress now insists on having the posttype declared in all lower case, despite be declaring the post types with capital letters

---

**Please, if you have any idea where to look for the issue, comment. No suggestion too small at this stage**

Comment: How did you create your custom post type? With a plugin or directly by inputing code into functions.php?

Comment: Using custom functions, which have not changed for long time prior to this issue.

Comment: Do you use the 'rewrite' argument in your 'register_post_type' function?

Comment: I don't.  I have updated my question to include the function I use.

Comment: If you set your permalinks to 'default' do you still got the 404?

Comment: Just this second came back to say no, I don't

Comment: @kevin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/974/discussion-between-mild-fuzz-and-kevin)

Comment: @kevin, you deserve the tick for this one!! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: glad you solved it, your answer is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

404's were being caused by problem with the WP Super Cache section in my .Htaccess file.

Greyed out areas AND metaboxes not showing up were being caused by Wordpress suddenly having a serious issue with using capitals at the start of Custom Post Type names.

Why these issues suddenly came to bite me? I have no idea!!